# Injecting base class with interface .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

I would like to ask you what kind of design pattern I am following here, some kind of Adapter?. Also do you recommend any simpler solution?

What I am trying to implement, is a validation pattern for different business implementations.

I have a **generic base class** that implement an interface. (Is it possible to use an abstract class?, how should be injected?)

```
public class BaseValidation<T> : IValidationHandler<T>
{
    public virtual void Validate(T modelToValidate)
    {
        //Base Implementation
    }
}
```

**Interface**

```
 public interface IValidationHandler<T>
 {
        void Validate(T modelToValidate);
 }
```

**Particular Implementation**

```
public class SpecificValidation : BaseValidation<SpecificDTO>
{
     public override void Validate(SpecificDTO modelToValidate)
     {
         base.Validate(modelToValidate);

         //Implement here specific validation 
     }
}
```

**Injection**

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IValidationHandler<>), typeof(BaseValidation<>));
services.AddScoped<BaseValidation<SpecificDTO>, SpecificValidation>();
```

Comment: I would think it's very close to Prototype pattern.

Comment: Hi Raju, Is not the main goal of the Prototy Pattern to implement cloning feature? Thanks

Comment: Implementation of cloning using prototype is just one use case. You can use prototype for lot of things.

Comment: On a side note, don't take patterns to the heart. Have a good understanding of SOLID and keep those in mind when writing code, patterns will naturally evolve (IMO).

Answer (score 0):

For auto injection all interfaces you can use services.Scan. For example:

```
        services
                .Scan(s =>
                {
                    s.FromAssemblies(assembly)
                        .AddClasses(classes => classes.Where(c =>
                        {
                            var allInterfaces = c.GetInterfaces();
                            return
                                Enumerable.Any<Type>(allInterfaces, y =>
                                    IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(y).IsGenericType && IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(y).GetGenericTypeDefinition() ==
                                    typeof(IValidationRuleHandler<>));
                        }))
                        .AsSelf()
                        .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                        .WithTransientLifetime();
                });
```

But for another developers it will be look like magic :) Only added implementations and it added to injection